# How can I access all of the text elements from this table (scrapy)?

Tags: python, scrapy

I think I am overthinking this and am failing to see the big picture. I have just started to attempt to make my first scrapy spider. I have usually in the past did scraping solely using selenium. I am trying to scrape the text from the left side table on: https://whattomine.com/coins/1-btc-sha-256. The column names would contain algorithm, block time, last block; the column values would contain "SHA-256," "10m 15s," "709,104," etc.

In scrapy shell this nearly gets me there:

```
key=response.css('dt:text')
val=response.css('dd:text')

data=dict(zip(key,val))
```

But for some of the values I get "\n". How can I get all of the values?

Comment: Some of the `<dd>` tags do have embedded newlines.  Are you thinking you need to remove them?  And, by the way, it looks to me like the `<dt>` tags are the key and rgw `<dd> tags are the value.

Comment: oops - yup i mixed up the tags while typing for keys vs. values. Yeah I'm essentially just looking for the best way to get all of the table data into a dictionary including the values under the embedded newlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The 'Ex rates' text are under 'a' tag so you're not getting them.
2. You need to get read of '\n'.

```py
In [1]: value = response.xpath('//dl/dd//text()').getall()

In [1]: key = response.xpath('//dl/dt/text()').getall()

In [2]: value = [v.strip() for v in value if v.strip()!='']

In [3]: value
Out[3]:
['SHA-256',
 '10m 3s',
 '709,114',
 '6.38',
 '6.38',
 '21,659,345M',
 '21,659,345M',
 '21,659,345M',
 '21,659,345M',
 '154,272.27 Ph/s',
 '$66,837.38 (Binance)',
 '$67,192.50 (Binance)',
 '$66,568.38 (Binance)',
 '$63,718.73 (Binance)',
 '44,571.56 BTC',
 '$1,261,169,962,655',
 '2,412.46 Days',
 '0.00 Days']

In [4]: data = dict(zip(key, value))

In [5]: data
Out[5]:
{'Algorithm:': 'SHA-256',
 'Block time:': '10m 3s',
 'Last block:': '709,114',
 'Bl. reward:': '6.38',
 'Bl. reward 24h:': '6.38',
 'Difficulty:': '21,659,345M',
 'Difficulty 24h:': '21,659,345M',
 'Difficulty 3 days:': '21,659,345M',
 'Difficulty 7 days:': '21,659,345M',
 'Nethash:': '154,272.27 Ph/s',
 'Ex. rate:': '$66,837.38 (Binance)',
 'Ex. rate 24h:': '$67,192.50 (Binance)',
 'Ex. rate 3 days:': '$66,568.38 (Binance)',
 'Ex. rate 7 days:': '$63,718.73 (Binance)',
 'Ex. volume 24h:': '44,571.56 BTC',
 'Market cap:': '$1,261,169,962,655',
 'Create 1 BTC in:': '2,412.46 Days',
 'Break even in:': '0.00 Days'}
```